# Is the following algebra 1-syzygy finite?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory

$\Lambda$ is a finite dimensional algebra given by

$$\begin{array}{rcccl}
           1  \rightrightarrows     2 \stackrel{\alpha}{\circlearrowright} \ \ \ \alpha^{3}=0\\
\end{array}$$

Is $\Lambda$ is 1-syzygy finite?

Comment: You might have to edit your diagram, it's not working (I don't think `xymatrix` is available here)

Comment: It seems you have to use \begin{array} for diagrams like this. An example of how to do this can be found here: https://legacy-www.math.harvard.edu/texman/node27.html

I have found this too much hassle and have avoided using diagrams in my answers for this reason.

Comment: Can you add the definition of "1-syzygy finite"?